# elm-test does not recognise reporter flag

Tags: json, junit, gitlab-ci, elm, elm-test

We decided to use JUnit xml files from our tests and upload them during CI as artifacts to Gitlab.

For elm, I followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-test?activeTab=readme and used

```
./node_modules/.bin/elm-test --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/elm app/frontend/elm/tests/ --reporter=junit
```

But it actually does nothing. Output is plain text.

```
MacBook-Pro-6:enectiva admin$ ./node_modules/.bin/elm-test --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/elm app/frontend/elm/tests/ --reporter=junit

elm-test 0.19.0
---------------

Running 286 tests. To reproduce these results, run: elm-test --fuzz 100 --seed 369554180583103 /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/BareTime/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ChartAndControlSet/AllEnergies/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ChartAndControlSet/ChartPort/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ChartAndControlSet/Data/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ChartAndControlSet/SingleEnergy/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/Disableable/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/Enectiva/Elm/I18n.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/Enectiva/EntityTree/EntityTree.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/Exports/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ExportStatePoller/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/ExportTemplate/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/HourFilter/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/PriceListForm/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/SelectionState/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/SourceSelection2/Tests.elm /Users/admin/go/src/enectiva.cz/enectiva/app/frontend/elm/tests/Visibility/Tests.elm


TEST RUN PASSED

Duration: 1049 ms
Passed:   286
Failed:   0
```

The same with `json`.

As I see from output from *reproduce* part, it looks like `elm-test` did not even notice the `reporter` flag.

Does anyone have idea for solution?

Comment: The flag is `--report` not `--reporter`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-test?activeTab=readme#--report

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. Thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

Typo, there should be used `report` instead of `reporter`.